# how does file system locate file's data?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver, ext2

I tried to remove inode of a specific file like this :

```
    ext2_filsys filsys;
    errcode_t error = ext2fs_open("/dev/sdb1",EXT2_FLAG_RW, 0, 0, unix_io_manager, &filsys);  // I know my file is located on /dev/sdb1
    ext2_ino_t ino = 13; // I found this number using ls -i command in terminal

    // first I read the inode to check that I am reading the correct one correctly
    struct ext2_inode inode;    
    errcode_t err_iread = ext2fs_read_inode(filsys, ino, &inode);

    // I change the data blocks pointers array and zero them all, then I change file size to zero
    unsigned int blocks_array[15] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    inode.i_size = 0;
    memcpy(&inode.i_block, &blocks_array, sizeof inode.i_block);  // I use this to remove data block indexes of the file.

    // I write the changed inode on to my desired file's inode
    errcode_t err_iwrite = ext2fs_write_inode(filsys, ino, &inode);
    errcode_t err_flush = ext2fs_flush(filsys);

    // Again I check that I have written the inode correctly
    err_iread = ext2fs_read_inode(filsys, ino, &inode);
    errcode_t err_close = ext2fs_close(filsys);
```

The problem is that I am still able to open the file from file browser application.
So my question is what is happening here? how is the file browser application able to locate data blocks of my file and open it?
I ran this code on ubuntu 14.0.4

Comment: May be due to cache

Comment: @Akshaya Do you know how do I empty cache ?

Comment: I am really sorry. I just made a guess on my experience on computer usage. I have not studied Linux Kernel because of I don't know from where to start. I just read arch/boot/x86 and got bored and now started coding my own kernel from scratch

Comment: @Akshaya I guess it would be boring too, filesystem programming isn't just boring but also killing me ;)

Comment: Thanks anyway, Its another lead